12 channel remote control: 4-pin IC for 12 buttons: How?
This RF remote control uses ev1527 encoder. Although this IC has just 4 pins for buttons, this remote control has 12 buttons. How they have done such thing?



what is this question asking?  ... How they have done such thing?

the diodes are probably used for a wired-or circuit to activate multiple pins with one button press

It looks like the diodes in the schematic are there to allow the ic to be powered when a button is pressed, and unpowered when a button is released.

Presumably the extra buttons on the board are wired such that multiple input pins are driven by each switch, allowing a maximum of 2^4 switches to be implemented

Please ask one question per question post, not 4; instead of voting to close due to being too broad, let me quickly remove the 2. to 4. question. You can still find them in your question's history, should you decide to ask some of them in separate posts at a later time :)


The 4 inputs are in binary. When you press any button, it both sets these 4 inputs to some value and powers the chip.

The diodes are used to set the 4 input pins based on which button you pressed. You can have one button setting only one bit, any two bits or any three bits. Each button sets an unique 4-bit pattern, except 0 because then no buttons are pushed. There could be up to 15 buttons, or if all bits high is not used, 14 buttons.

Unknown how you can extend the range. Maybe you should not. Extending the range means it transmits at higher power, and that is a problem as in many jurisdictions using, posessing or manufacturing an illegal transmitter which is more powerful than allowed is illegal. If you need more range, use another technology that already has higher range.

As explained, you have more than 4 buttons so each of them has a unique 4-bit code. You can't push two buttons, or it would match a code for some other, third button. In the original schematics, each button does control each bit separately, but if the button code is only read when chip starts, it will send button code of the first button it sees, i.e. reads the bits once.



When you look at the logic table on P.2 of the datasheet, you'll see that for certain combinations of pins getting pulled high, you get specific data output. You can pull multiple pins high with a single button press! (You need to add diodes to the output of your button, so that you don't generally short all pins together).

In larger keypads:
Arrays of keys are usually scanned in a matrix style: you arrange your buttons (logically, where you put them on the board later on is purely up to your trace routing skills) in a square.
Then, you connect the first contact buttons of each of the rows to one set of pins, and the columns to the other contacts.
That way, you first "activate" the first row (by pulling the pin high), and measure the voltage on all column pins. If there's a pin that suddenly is high, you found that the button that connects this row to this column was pressed. Easy!
Now, add diodes and you can a second (logical) square of buttons, by measuring whether something is connected, in both directions of potential current flow (i.e., instead of pulling the rows up and measuring how much current flows to ground through the column pins, you pull the rows down and measure how much current flows to the column pins when they go to supply voltage).

I'm not sure the mention of scanning a keyboard matrix makes sense in terms of the EV1527 encoder which is the subject of the question. As far as can tell from the datasheet the EV1527 doesn't have any capability to scan a keyboard matrix, it just has four data input pins.

@ChesterGillon you're right, I got this knotted up in my head
