Can we use telescopic antenna for RF receivers?
Can we use TE antenna for receiver? Because I have seen that TE antenna is used in transmitters and for receivers spring coil antenna is used.
The reason that I have asked this question is I have seen a telescope antenna in the security system control panel board. And because they are receiver of motion detectors, I got this question to ask.


it seems you already answered your question with "yes". So, what's the question then?

Portable AM/FM radios and televisions with telescoping antennas used to be extremely common, these are receivers.
Spring coil antennas are used when you want the antenna to be short while in use, telescoping antennas are used when you want the antenna to be short for storage, but longer when in use.

Thanks for your reply. Can we increase the rang by adding both kinds of antennas?

@Saeed You wouldn’t normally use two kinds of antennas together, if you want more range you use a more efficient antenna. Coiled antennas tend to sacrifice efficiency for small size. Antennas are also frequency dependent, the higher the frequency the shorter the antenna. If the signal you are trying to receive is coming from only one direction a directional antenna such as a Yagi will give better performance.

I know it is not normal, but I have a remote control that they used both, that's why I am asking. here you can see it. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/719350/12-channel-remote-control-4-pin-ic-for-12-buttons-how

@Saeed I only see one antenna on that. There are some inductors near the top but I don’t think those are antennas.

@Saeed next time, ask what you wanted to ask ("is this a second antenna on my remote control? if so, how does the system work?") instead of asking a different, "detour" question like "can telescope antennas be used in receivers".

OMG, what a mistake that I made. Thank you for your help
